# Сравнение результата деления без остатка с нулём

Tags: javascript

Зачем тут сравнение с `0`?

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
```

Я так понимаю, тут происходит деление без остатка, но не понимаю зачем потом сравнивать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это проверка на то что остаток от деления числа `i` на другое число (`3`) равен 0.

Обычно так делается для того чтобы выполнять какое-то действие в цикле, но не каждый раз (в данном случае только каждый 3 раз).

Например:

- раскрасить каждую 2 строку в списке другим цветом `if(i % 2 == 0) ...`
- показать на экране прогресс при каждой 10 итерации `if(i % 10 == 0) ...`
- разделить поток цифр, добавив  пробел после каждых 3 `if(i % 3 == 0) ...`
- и т.п.

Answer (score 7):

Знак `%` это получение остатка от деления, в вашем случае это проверка на то, что число `i` делется нацело на `3`.

Подробнее об операторах JS можно прочитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: спасибо, уже разобралась)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova не за что, если ответ решил ваш вопрос, то можете отметить его галочкой

Answer (score 1):

Это оператор модуля, который возвращает остаток от деления. Например, `18 % 7` будет равно `4` (будет примерно `18 - 14 = 4`). А если любое число проверяете на ноль - тогда вы проверяете, делится ли это число нацело на какое-то.

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать свой ответ точнее.